# train an ai on laptop using tensorflow and execute on raspberry pi

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, raspberry-pi3

i`m doing a school project and decided to use tensorflow to train an object detection. my question is, is it possible to train the ai on a laptop and once the training is done and deploy it on a raspberry pi?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you have to consider the difference in architectures. Your laptop/PC is most likely a 64-bit x86, but a Raspberry Pi is a 64-bit ARM. You need to check if the Tensorflow build on different archs is compatible with each other (maybe not).

Comment: Given the downvotes it seems like I am in the minority, but I think the question is OK. It's a specific question about tools commonly used and has a practical answer (which happens to be "yes"). I could see the point if he/she said "**Show me how to** train the model on laptop then serve on raspberry pi" but that's not what he/she asked. He/she asked if it was *possible*. It is. The OP has a practical, answerable question that's entirely relevant - no??

Comment: well, it it can be done, how could i do it?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can, however, the best way is to train on a cloud!
because training takes too much time and your machine suffers

Comment: hello. I used both Google Colab free TPU and my laptop (average intel) and laptop is faster.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes absolutely. This is possible.

It's even possible to train a model on vast cloud infrastructure then use it in a browser using tensorflow js. Why not check out the documentation and ask a new (specific) question if you get stuck somewhere.

Some links to get you started:

- [load a keras model in tensorflow js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_keras)
- [Convert a saved model to tflite for inference](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/get_started#tensorflow_lite_converter)